# Google Analytics - Incorrect Revenue (refunds)

Tags: gtag.js, google-analytics-4

I've noticed that the product revenue shows incorrect values.

---

Example:

The user buys

3000 HUF item (**qty: 2**)

The total is **6000 HUF**

---

The user refunds one item

So -3000 HUF

The revenue should be 3000 now, but it is still 6000... what do I do wrong?

You see, the **Product Refund Amount** is correct, but the **Product Revenue** is not:

[image]

My refund code:

```
  gtag('event', 'refund', {
      'transaction_id': 'ID',
      'value': "3000",
      'currency': 'HUF',
      'items': [{
        'id': '01',
        'name': 'PRINGLES',
        'quantity': 1,
        'price': '3000',
      }]
    });
```

This is also the same case as when I refund a whole order.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in financial terms 'revenue' (or 'total revenue') is the total of sales, including the amount that was refunded. What you're looking for is the 'net revenue', which is not directly available in GA sales performance report.

You'll need to create a calculated metric where you subtract the refund amount from product revenue. Here is the documentation: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121409?hl=en